# Properties or fields in Equals and GetHashCode?

Tags: c#

I'm using a mix of [Jon Skeet's GetHashCode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/47493) and the [MSDN Guidelines for Overloading Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to implement my Equals and GetHashCode methods. However, one thing has been bothering me.

Should I implement them checking against the actual fields in the class, or their properties?

Furthermore, what about a parent class's properties with fields that are private (thus I can't access them) - should I be checking those as well, and then should I check them via their properties?

Comment: it depends on your definition of equals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'll make my comment an answer.

It really depends on your definition of equals on how detailed you should implement it. Properties are nothing more than over-glorified fields. I probably wouldn't hash a read-only, calculated property.